# Immutable event handling

Tags: java

I have implemented an immutable system in Java. Pretty much every class is immutable and it's worked out much better than I expected.

My problem is trying to send events. Normally you'd have an event source and an event listener. The source simply holds a reference to the listener and sends the event when it happens.

But with immutables the event listener reference changes when you modify a field and create a new object. So the event source is sending to some old reference that's been garbage collected.

So all my GUI classes are mutable for that reason, because they naturally use a lot of events. But i'd like to find an elegant way to handle events so I can make those immutable as well.

Edit: Example code as requested:

```
public final class ImmutableButton {
    public final String text;

    public ImmutableButton(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    protected void onClick() {
        // notify listeners somehow, hoping they haven't changed
    }
}

public final class ImmutableWindow {
    public final ImmutableButton button;

    public ImmutableWindow(ImmutableButton button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    protected void listenForButtonClick() {
        // somehow register with button and receive events, despite this object
        // being entirely recreated whenever a field changes
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm.. The part "But with immutables the event listener reference changes when you modify a field and create a new object" is not clear to me. As I understand it, a reference never changes. And an object will _never_ handle a reference which has already been collected by the GC.

Comment: Having immutable objects and events reacting on changes on them doesn't make any sense. Either they are immutable and they cannot be changed, so change events on them doesn't make sense OR there are change events on objects you change, but this means they aren't immutable anymore. Please add your source code and/or some diagrams to your question, showing us what you want to do.

Comment: Progman, see the java String class for a counter example to your claim.

Comment: Santi, traditionally when you modify an immutable you just create a new object.  That means the reference to the object is now different and the old one is gone.

Comment: @LegendLength The content of a String object cannot be changed and there are no events on the String class either. Again, having change events on immutable objects which cannot be changed doesn't make any sense. Please add your source code and/or some diagrams to your question, showing us what you want to do.

Comment: Who is talking about 'change' events?  What makes you think every event needs to be in reaction to a data change?  If you see the actual example I used it was a GUI button press which changes nothing in the button.

Comment: @LegendLength I assumed it was about a change event because your event source was set to an old object, where such a change event would be generated. Since thats not the case: Please add the source code you have which shows the problem you have. When you get an event from an "old object" which shouldn't be used, then there is something wrong that you get such an event from an invalid source. Please edit your question to elaborate the problem you have with events and immutable objects.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you would need source code for this.  It's a general question about immutable objects and event handling.  Do you have any experience in that area at all?

Comment: @LegendLength There usually are no problems with immutable objects and/or events. So I assume there is some problem with something you are working on or you think there are some problems with a design you have. So when you show us some source code or some diagram which shows why you get events on an old reference as the event source, we can help you with the problem.

Comment: I will but first tell me how you handled events.  Did you use something global like java event bus?  When you modified the listener did you update the reference in the sender object?

Comment: BTW, why Immutability is a must for your design?

Comment: Could Java reflection be a solution? Search for the methods you want to invoke for events by searching for them with a custom annotation? But then you still need a reference to the object getting the event. I agree with @Program where you have underlying problem, you have a reference that isn't being updated somewhere we can't see

Comment: one question: is a copy constructor an option? where you could simply create a `clone` of your objects? I might have read this question too fast btw...

Answer (score 3):

GUIs are good case where mutability is more handy and more performant to use as object model. You create one backing model for a GUI component with fields ready for read and write operations. User mutates the display, which gets reflected to the backing model - all happening in one object. Imagine having to recreate an object everytime user changes something on one component? That will surely hog your system.

Albeit the disadvantage, if you really want your GUI objects to be immutable, you can create a global event bus to solve the listener attachment problem. In this way, you don't need to worry about the object instance which the event listener will be registered. The event bus will be responsible for dispatching of events, registration of listener, and maintenance of the mapping between them.

Here is a draft design for a simple event bus.

```
public class EventBus {

    private Map<Event, List<EventListener>> REGISTRY;

    public void registerEventListener(Event event, EventListener listener) {
        List<EventListener> listeners = REGISTRY.getOrDefault(event, new ArrayList<>());
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent(Event event, Object... args) {
        List<EventListener> listeners = REGISTRY.get(event);

        if(listeners != null) {
            for(EventListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.handleEvent(args);
            }
        }
    }
}

// The events
enum Event {
    ADD_BUTTON_CLICKED, DELETE_BUTTON_CLICKED;
}

// Listeners must conform to one interface
interface EventListener {
    public void handleEvent(Object... args);
}
```

**EDIT**

Listeners are handlers - they are supposed to perform business logic and not to hold state. Also, they are not supposed to be attached to a component. In your code above, the listener code must be decoupled from `ImmutableWindow` - both should be standing on its own. The interaction between `ImmutableWindow` and `ImmutableButton` must be configured (in the event bus) somewhere during the startup of your application.

You should also have a central registry of your UI components where it can be identified by a unique id and use this registry to find (traverse the component tree) the latest instance of the component and interact with.

In practice, something like this...

```
// The main class. Do the wirings here.
public class App {

    @Inject
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ImmutableWindow window = new ImmutableWindow ();
        ImmutableButton addButton = new ImmutableButton ();

        eventBus.registerEventListener(Events.ADD_BUTTON_CLICKED, new AddButtonClickListener());
    }
}

public class AddButtonClickListener implements EventListener  {

    @Inject
    private SomeOtherService someOtherSvc;

    @Inject
    private UiRegistry uiRegistry;

    public void handleEvent(Object... args) {
        ImmutableButton addButton = args[0].getSource; // The newset instance of the button must be packed and delivered to the eventlistners when firing an event
        ImmutableWindow targetWindow = uiRegistry.lookUp("identifier_of_the_window", ImmutableWindow.class);

        // Perform interaction between the two components;
    }
}
```

Now you have a totally decoupled UI and business logic. You can recreate your components all you want, the listeners will not be affected because they are not attached to any component.

Comment: Event bus just seems to shift the issue.  When a listener gets recreated (i.e. changes state) then it needs to be re-registered with the bus.  A bus helps a bit by centralizing it all but still doesn't seem elegant in that respect.  As for GUI not being a good fit I agree, but my question is about immutable systems and events in general.  GUI was just an easy example that shows the difficulty with the whole issue.

Comment: The thing is UiRegistry.lookup() still needs to look through a list of objects to find the right one.  So any time an object is recreated, that list needs to be updated.  Now you can't rely on garbage collection because you have to update that list on every object delete and create.  But you'll definitely get the bounty because no one else has even understood the question besides yourself, and this is the 2nd or 3rd post i've made on it over the last few months.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the conflict in your design is you cant register listeners against objects which get replaced when you rebuild the immutable data model.  My solution below is to remove the listeners from the model all together.  Even thought most of your objects are immutable, you'll need at least 1 mutable variable at the base to hold the created / recreated Window.  Here I'v used inner classes as listeners which you register once. They then dispatch doStuff() calls against the objects in the model, but they get looked up against the single base mutable window reference.  eg. `window.getButton1().doStuff();`

I don't claim this is a great solution but it's the simplest and cleanest I could come up with for your requirements.  The listeners don't become invalid and everything from Window down can be immutable.

```
public final MutableBase {
    private ImmutableWindow window;  // single mutable variable

    public MutableBase() {
        Magic.registerClickListener(new WindowClickEvent());
        Magic.registerClickListener(new Button1ClickEvent());
        rebuildWindow();
    }

    public void rebuildWindow() {
        // rebuild here when needed - change single mutable variable
        this.window = new ImmutableWindow(new ImmutableButton("text"));
    }

    class WindowClickEvent implements ClickListener {
        public void onClick() {
            this.window.doStuff();
        }
    }

    class Button1ClickEvent implements ClickListener {
        public void onClick() {
            this.window.getButton1().doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to make everything immutable because somewhere you need to store a changing system state (usually, in the model). Let me explain with some example. Sorry for the lengthy reply, I'm trying to be as clear as possible as this is a complex issue.

I assume that you want to follow MVC (model view controller) paradigm for your GUI. Your example code is not so clear so I will rewrite it to proper MVC.

In MVC, the V (view) listens to changes in the model M and updates the display accordingly.

In general, a listenable like M contains a Set (eg. the View V and Controller C). M must remain the same object in memory because it's shared by several users (V and C). It has to contain a "addListener" function that changes the Set in the *original* object. If it would only create a modified local copy of M, addListener would add the listener only for the object that calls addListener, but not the original that is used by the objects that want to *call* the added listener. Therefore a listenable in general can not be immutable.

Let me make this more specific, if this was too dense.

Your code is not proper MVC so I modify it to this to introduce the Model M.

```
public class Model {
  final?? boolean clicked = false;
  final?? Set<Listeners> listeners

  void addChangeListener(l) {
    listeners.add(l);
  }

  void doClick() { 
    clicked = true; // can not be final ? 
    listeners.forEach(l -> l.notifyChange(..event..));
  }

  boolean getClickedState() {
    return clicked; // makes no sense if final ? 
  }
}

public final class ImmutableWindow {
  final Model model;
  public ImmutableWindow(Model m) {
    this.model = m;
    this.model.addChangeListener( evt -> 
      updatePanel(this.model.getClickedState() );
  }
}

public final class ImmutableButton {
  final Model model;
  public ImmutableButton(Model m) {
    this.model = m
  }

    protected void onClick() {
        this.model.doClick();
    }
}
```

The Model extends the listener pattern. Now it even has 2 properties that require it to be mutable
1. The Model must reflect the actual state of the system. 
2. The Model is observable, so it contains a mutable set of listeners.

@1. m.doClick and m.getClickedState() would work (change Model/system state) only if Model is mutable. The field Model.clicked can't be final.

@2. listenable can't be immutable,as discussed  above.

Now notice that ImmutableButton and ImmutableWindow are not really immutable anymore, because Model will turn out to be mutable. The "final" annotations will still work though because final only refers to the object reference , not to the contents of the referred object.

Alternatively, you might propose to make Model immutable and let it just forward all changes of Model to its listeners. But then ImmutableButton would have to store updates of the model. But if it would, then ImmutableButton.model can not be final and the ImmutableButton object would not be immutable...

In the end, someone has to store the changed objects. In MVC it's in the model, but whatever you do,  the object that stores the change will be immutable.

I think the idea above with the event bus tries to hide the model behind some interface. The idea being that the interface can be the same fixed (or even static) object that it can point to some mutable data. But it does not work, as any object pointing to some mutable object also is mutable. Specifically, any object containing a mutable eventBus is mutable.

More radically you might try to remove the whole event and Listeners. But I don't see how to do the event handling without the shared listener system.

The best solution I have is to *minimize* the mutability of the model. Put only a SINGLE mutable object in the model, like SystemState, and mutate only that.